# I want rows to be clickable an that highlights the corresponding button in the row.How to do it?

Tags: jsp

My  HTML table fetches data from database.The row from database is fetched in HTML table.Each table also have a button. I want to click a particular row and highlight that particular button.

```
  try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lvcdatabase","root","java");
        String query = "Select * from kitchentable;";
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs =pst.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
   %>

   <form action="processorder" method="">
      <table id="example" >
      <%String s = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("orderno"));%>
        <tr id="row<%=s%>" onclick="a(<%=s%>)">
          <td><%=rs.getInt("orderno")%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
          <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
          <td><input class="service" id="service<%=s%>" onclick="b(<%=s%>)" type="button" value="Service Status"></td>
         </tr>




         <tr id="buttonrow">
           <td colspan="1"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:#ff0000" value="Pending" id="redbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:#ffbf50" value="Cooking" id="amberbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"><input type="button" style="background-color:#66ff66" value="Cooked" id="greenbutton<%=s%>" class="statusbutton"></td>
           <td colspan="1"></td>
         </tr>



   </form><br>
   <%} %>
   </table>
   <%rs.close();
   pst.close();
   conn.close();
   }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    %>
```

My javascript code:
(searches over google helped me nd i got the desired output)

```
<script>

function a(x){
    document.getElementById("redbutton"+x).style.backgroundColor ="#b20000";
    document.getElementById("redbutton"+x).value="Queued";
   document.getElementById("amberbutton"+x).style.backgroundColor="#ffbf00";
    document.getElementById("amberbutton"+x).value ="Processing";
}

function b(x){

document.getElementById("greenbutton"+x).style.backgroundColor="green";
document.getElementById("amberbutton"+x).style.backgroundColor="#ffbf50";
document.getElementById("service"+x).value="Serviced";

}
```

Comment: Tables don't fetch anything; fetched data gets displayed in a table.

Comment: post some code and we may be able to help you more.I suggest creating a jsfiddle